# nodejs mongoose showing error while deploying to aws, working on local machine

Tags: node.js, github, mongoose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://node-sandbox:" +
    process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW +
      "@node-sandbox-2hdom.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    }
  )
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("printing mongoose error - " + err);
  });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

A nodejs project showing error while deploying on aws using CodePipeline and github whereas working perfectly when running on my local machine.

error   -

```
printing mongoose error - MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.
printing mongoose error - MongooseServerSelectionError: bad auth Authentication failed. 


connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.37.102, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "172.31.8.154"
```

**EDIT :**
I am new to backend development.
Getting this response while trying to connect via postman -

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't think there is any issue with mongo connection, in mongo console it is showing one connection which can be this only. so there is any other issue! Cannot find out the issue!
Maybe some http/https issue.

Comment: The code looks good, are you sure process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW has the correct value on AWS?

Comment: for a while I have added .env file in the githhub as well so that environment variables would be same as of development. But still its not working. Any other way to add env variables on aws? @Chcamiloam

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same problem, I had to add the files required for my application to run in the buildspec.yml

When it was failing my buildspec.yml file had just the code bellow on the artifacts section:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - app.js
    - package.json
```

I fixed it adding node_modules/**/*

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - app.js
    - package.json
    - node_modules/**/*
```